# What is the equivalent of OVER (PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY TranDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) for Firebird v2.5?

Tags: window-functions, firebird

I need an equivalent way to getting `OVER (PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY TranDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)` for Firebird v2.5

Here is the full code:

```sql
DECLARE @Test TABLE (
    Account     INTEGER,
    TranDate    DATE,
    TranAmount  NUMERIC(5,2));
INSERT INTO @Test (Account, TranDate, TranAmount)
VALUES  (1, '2015-01-01', 50.00),
        (1, '2015-01-15', 25.00),
        (1, '2015-02-01', 50.00),
        (1, '2015-02-15', 25.00),
        (2, '2015-01-01', 50.00),
        (2, '2015-01-15', 25.00),
        (2, '2015-02-01', 50.00),
        (2, '2015-02-15', 25.00);
SELECT  Account, TranDate, TranAmount,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Account
                       ORDER BY TranDate
                       ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS RowNbr,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TranDate) AS DateCount,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Account
                       ORDER BY TranDate
                       ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Last2Count
FROM    @Test
ORDER BY Account, TranDate;
```

and `ROW_NUMBER()` equivalent if possible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: seem to be present in 3.0.4 https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html. Can you upgrade?

Comment: @Lennart I guess I have to upgrade to version 3.0.5. Because I am missing a lot of features here.

Comment: You can emulate most of it ( if not all of it) , but it is neither pretty nor efficient. So it is probably better to upgrade.